# logging usability in python

Tags: python-3.x, logging, valueerror

I am implementing a simple logger in python.Find my code below, Sometimes it runs fine,at times I get `ValueError at  self.log('INFO','Append operation successful.')`

Where am I doing wrong? I am new to python and have also referred to the doc. Unable to understand the inconsistency, also I am using python 3.9, tried using force parameter too. It is also not logging the level, like Critical, Info or Error.

```
import logging as logger
class data:
    def __init__(self, filename,filetype,filesize,date):
        self.filename=filename
        self.filetype=filetype
        self.filesize=filesize
        self.date=date
        
    def log(self,logtype,msg):
        logger.basicConfig(filename="datalog.log",level=logger.INFO,force=True,format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
        if logtype == "INFO":
            logger.info(msg)
        elif logtype == "ERROR":
            logger.ERROR(msg)
        elif logtype == "CRITICAL":
            logger.CRITICAL(msg)
        else:
            logger.info(msg)
        
    def openFile(self):
        try:
            filename=self.filename+self.filetype
            f=open(filename,'w+')
            f.write("Hello, Lets learn OOPs in Python")
            f.close()
            self.log('INFO','Write operation successful.')
        except Exception as e:
            self.log('ERROR','Writing operation failed.')
        
    def appendFile(self):
        try:
            f=open(self.filename+self.filetype,'a')
            f.write("Appending some extra content")
            f.close()
            self.log('INFO','Append operation successful.')
        except Exception as e:
            self.log('ERROR','Append operation failed.')

sample = data('sample','.txt','1Mb','2021-08-20')
sample.appendFile()
sample.openFile()
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Unrecognised argument(s): force

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e095529812fd> in log(self, logtype, msg)
     12             logger.info(msg)
     13         elif logtype == "ERROR":
---> 14             logger.ERROR(msg)
     15         elif logtype == "CRITICAL":
     16             logger.CRITICAL(msg)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: File Colab link: [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/147wsDDFuunVUwPwKLjuX6wGMQaAv93LD?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please copy the entire error message into your question as code.

Comment: @itprorh66 I have added the error message. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`force`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) option to `basicConfig` is only available in Python 3.8+.  Check your Python version.

Also, it's probably not a good idea to force reconfigure the logging system on each and every log event. Just configure it once, at the main entry point of your application.

Comment: it worked, thanks, couldn't upvote due to less reputation.